# How to get order number of file in dropzone.js?

Tags: file-upload, dropzone.js

When I upload files via dropzone and save them, I add order number to the names of files (file_name_1, file_name_2, ...). How do I do that? Existing number of files in folder + 1. But... files in dropzone are being uploaded in parallel mode, so it is possible that number for two file will be the same and one file rewrite another. I think that it would be a good idea to take some order number of file from dropzone and send it to server. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not use a time stamp instead?

Comment: Can you be more clear? You want to send additional data with each uploading file?

Comment: When you add files to dropzone, they should have its own order numbers. I want to send those numbers as additional data.